# VBA Find value not found

Tags: excel, vba, find

I need some help as I am beginner in VBA. I have code that is looking for value "xstart" in multiple worksheets to define the range of the cells that needs to be deleted. I am having problem in the situation when there is no value "xstart" exsiting in the worksheet. How can I handle it?

```
Sub TestReset()

YesNo = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the data?", vbYesNo)

Select Case YesNo
    Case vbYes
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            If sht.Name <> "Sheet1" And sht.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
                Dim iRow As Long, iMax As Long
                iRow = sht.Cells.Find(What:="xstart", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

                iMax = sht.Cells(iRow, "A").End(xlDown).Row
                sht.Range("A" & iRow & ":AY" & iMax).ClearContents
            End If
        Next sht

    MsgBox ("Data has been cleared.")

Case vbNo

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if the variable that stores the `Find` object is empty:

```
Sub TestReset()
Dim iRow As Range
Dim iMax As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

YesNo = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the data?", vbYesNo)

If YesNo = vbYes Then
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sht.Name <> "Sheet1" And sht.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
            Set iRow = sht.Cells.Find(What:="xstart", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not iRow Is Nothing Then
                iMax = sht.Cells(iRow.Row, "A").End(xlDown).Row
                sht.Range("A" & iRow.Row & ":AY" & iMax).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next sht

    MsgBox ("Data has been cleared.")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the contribution! However when I try to execute this code I am receiving following error: related to "iRow" Compile Error, Type Mismatch. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @jan.f my bad, edited. A `Find` object is a `Range` object. You can extract the row from that, as you did in a one-liner, but this is *only* possible when the search query is actually found. So: search for the range first, and if found, extract the property you require.

Comment: Glad to hear it does! If you found an answer to have fully solved your question, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 1):

If the phrase you are searching for is found, the `Range.Find` method returns a Range object, namely the cell where the phrase was found. If the phrase is not found, the method returns `Nothing`.

You can read more here: [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

That's the problem you are running into. When "xstart" is found, `sht.Cells.Find(...)` returns a cell, and you can reference the Row property of that cell. When "xstart" is not found, the Find method returns `Nothing`. `Nothing` doesn't have a Row property, so `sht.Cells.Find(...).Row` fails.

To prevent a program error, you need to add a check for whether the `Find` method returned `Nothing`, like this:

```
Set MyRange = sht.Cells.Find(What:="xstart", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
    iRow = MyRange.Row
    'etc.
```

Observe that you do not check whether iRow (the desired row number) is `Nothing`. You check whether Find returns a range or `Nothing`. If it returns a range, you can then read the Row property of that range.